# How can I control my object's direction in javascript through mouse?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on one html5 game project. In this I have to control my object direction through mouse. I have already control it from keyboard. But I want to implement Mouse controlling. So anybody can Help then reply me.

Comment: Are you using a framework? jQuery, etc?

Comment: [jQuery.mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    var refObj = $('#image-id');  // reference object selector
    var objPos = refObj.offset(); // get object's absolute position
    var objCenterPos = {          // get object's center absolute position
        x: objPos.left + refObj.width()  / 2,
        y: opjPos.top  + refObj.height() / 2
    };
    var refPos = { // compute mouse position relative to reference object
        x: e.pageX - objCenterPos.x,
        y: e.pageY - objCenterPos.y
    };

    updateDirectionVector(refPos); // refPos is also the direction vector
});

function updateDirectionVector(vector) {
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'onmousemove' and capture its event

```
window.onmousemove = functionName;

functionName(event){
    //now read the relevant event properties for the mouse
    //console.log(event); //use console.log to get a list of possible event properties
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;

}
```

you need to track previous locations and do lots of other stuff within that function but there is a lot of documentation out there to get you started.

Try this link: 
http://orangesplotch.com/mouse_follower-javascript_tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The following code might give you some idea!

```
var refPos = {x:window.event.clientX,y:window.event.clientY};

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
var curPos = {x:window.event.clientX,y:window.event.clientY};
var left = refPos.x - curPos.x;
var top = refPos.y - curPos.y;
var direction = "";
direction += (top < 0)?"South":"North";
direction += (left <0)?"East":"West";
alert("Relative Direction " + direction);
},true);
```

Hope this is of some help!